# Using jQuery what's the way to get all elements of a queried set EXCEPT the first.

Tags: javascript, jquery, set

Using jQuery what's the way to get all elements of a queried set EXCEPT the first. I forget offhand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
$(selector).not(':first');
```

Or:

```
$('selector:not(:first)');
```

Comment: Oh okay.  I was thinking I recalled the .not function as inverting the selection or something... :P

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are refering to the [NOT selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not) .

Answer (score 2):

$("div.someClass:not(div.someClass:first)")

Assuming of course you are looking for div.someClass.  This might be a bit verbose, but I think it works. Haven't tested.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the [`gt` selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/gt) (greater than):

```
$('selector:gt(0)');
```

or

```
$('selector').gt(0);
```

`:not(:first)` is more readable, but also a bit longer.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), e.g.

```
var nodes = $(selector);
nodes.splice(0, 1);
```